# How to center element inside SVG polygon

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I have SVG that is assembled from multiple polygons.
I am trying to put image/button inside polygon center but what ever I try it always put image in `x=0 and y=0` of the screen.

```
<Svg width="546px" height="794px" viewBox="0 0 546 794" version="1.1" >
    <G id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <G id="item0" transform="translate(1.000000, 1.000000)" fill="#EDAF51" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#720D00">
            <Polygon id="RX-03" points="206.65269...">
            </Polygon>
            <Circle x="0" y="0" cx="40" cy="40" r="15" fill="black" />              
        </G>
```

With this I get:

[image]

But if I put `<Circle x="110" y="0"` I get

[image]

And this is correct but I don't want to use x=110 I am trying to **make this circle to be relative to it's parent polygon**.
So I can set circle to x=0 y=0 and to keep it inside area of parent polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer on the comment of the author of the question

In `svg`, with mutual positioning between elements, there is only absolute positioning.
Relative positioning in svg, as you want - there is no circle relative to the parent polygon. 
Only absolute positioning of a circle will help to place it in the right place
You can create a circle once and clone it several times while positioning:

`<use xlink:href="#crc1" x="100" y="150"  />`

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="546px" height="794px" viewBox="0 0 546 794" >
  <defs>
    <circle id="crc1" cx="0" cy="0" r="15" stroke="red" />
</defs> 
 <image transform="translate(0, -300)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0PXl.png"
             width="100%" height="100%"
        />
  <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="100" y="150"  />
    <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="210" y="110"  />
      <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="300" y="190"  /> 
     <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="385" y="190"  />
       <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="500" y="190"  />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly then I can’t put circle in one polygon and make circle relative to it?

Comment: @1110 Yes you can’t. Only absolute positioning. As done in my new answer. But this is easy to do once as in my example. But the layout will never break and will be adaptive to any gadget

Answer (score 1):

An image can be inserted into any SVG shape in several ways:

1. Using `clipPath`
2. Using `mask`
3. Using `pattern`

With any method of inserting an image, you need to focus on the shape of the template.

If the template has a symmetrical shape, it is necessary to select the original image with the same aspect ratio.

In other words, if the cropping pattern is a circle or regular polygons, then you need to select images with the same width and height.

*I translated the React syntax into the regular SVG syntax. If necessary, you can go back*

Selected round image `badge`

[image]

Insert this image into the hexagon`

### 1. Using `clipPath`

The hexagon acts as a cropping pattern.

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 546 794"  >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
     <path fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="2" d="m275.9 190.9 175.6 101.4 0 202.7-175.6 101.4-175.6-101.4 0-202.7z" />
    </clipPath> 
</defs> 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOrJU.png"
       x="0"y="0"
       width="100%" height="100%"
       clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
</div>
```

### 2. Using `mask`

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
image {
 mask:url(#msk1);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 546 794" >
  <defs>
    <mask id="msk1">
     <path fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="12" d="m275.9 190.9 175.6 101.4 0 202.7-175.6 101.4-175.6-101.4 0-202.7z" />
    </mask> 
</defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOrJU.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
```

### 3. Using `pattern`

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

path {
fill:url(#ptn1);
stroke:#DBC176;
stroke-width:8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 546 794"  >
  <defs>
    <pattern id="ptn1" width="1" height="1">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOrJU.png" x="-24" y="3" width="400px" height="400px"  /> 
    </pattern> 
</defs> 
 
 <path  d="m275.9 190.9 175.6 101.4 0 202.7-175.6 101.4-175.6-101.4 0-202.7z" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please check my update in question. I think that problem is how to set origin so that child of polygon are relative to that polygon. I explained problem in question.

Comment: @1110 Hi, in `svg`, with mutual positioning between elements, there is only absolute positioning.  
Relative positioning in svg, as you want - there is no circle relative to the parent polygon. 
Only absolute positioning of a circle will help to place it in the right place
You can create a circle once and clone it several times while positioning
Do you want me to make a new answer?